# Android java AlertDialog error in AsyncTask

Tags: java, android, android-asynctask, android-dialogfragment, android-dialog

When I create AlertDialog in backgroud background thread AsyncTask,  I get error. if I create AlertDialog outside of AsyncTask its working great. How I can fix that?

```
final ProgressDialog mDialog = new ProgressDialog(PageAndExercise.this);
            mDialog.setMessage(getString(R.string.loading));
            mDialog.setCancelable(false);
            mDialog.show();
alertDialog2 = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
        AsyncTask.execute(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {

                    mDialog.dismiss();
                    alertDialog2.setTitle(getString(R.string.tnxupload));
                    // Setting Dialog Message
                    alertDialog2.setMessage(getString(R.string.tnxupload2));
                    alertDialog2
                            .setCancelable(false)
                            .setPositiveButton("", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {

                                }

                            })
                            .setNegativeButton(getString(R.string.tnxupload3), new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                                    // if this button is clicked, just close
                                    // the dialog box and do nothing
                                    dialog.cancel();

                                }
                            });

                    AlertDialog alertDialog = alertDialog2.create();

                    // show it
                    alertDialog2.show();


            }
        });
```

The error:

```
28928-31794/com.example.exampleE/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #5
Process: com.example.example, PID: 28928
java.lang.RuntimeException: Can't create handler inside thread that has not called Looper.prepare()
```

Comment: What kind of error? Can you add full stack trace please?

Comment: what you are trying to do by passing `new Runnable()` in `execute` method? and also `execute` is not `static` method how accessing it using class name ?

Comment: You don't need `Runnable()` inside `AsyncTask` as AsynTask's `doInBackground()` runs on worker thread. and you can access application ui in other methods of asynctask. So in sort AsyncTask is substitute of your `Runnable` and `Message Handler` with more efficient way.

Comment: I am also not sure I'd you are using asyncTask correctly, see [example](http://www.compiletimeerror.com/2013/01/why-and-how-to-use-asynctask.html?m=1)

Comment: @mrek I have a ProgressDialog before `new Runnable()`. I edited the code

Comment: @Ron: then `mDialog.dismiss();` line causing issue

Comment: Not sure this is going to solve your problem but you could try adding: if (Looper.myLooper() == null) { Looper.prepare(); } in doInBackground()

Comment: @ρяσѕρєяK its not. without mDialog its not working too.
@mjp66 its not working.
The link of causing issue is `AlertDialog alertDialog = alertDialog2.create();`

Comment: By the way, it is better solution to use [anonymous class](http://stackoverflow.com/a/24827535/3894977) before Runnable - you have multiple methods there: onPreExecute, onPostExecute - where you can work with Views (show or hide something); then you have doInBackground(..) method, which is something like run in Runnable. I suggest you to read more in [official documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html).
In addition, I'd like to see **full** stack trace.

Answer (score 0):

You should look more into what `AsyncTask` does and why.

It is a convenience class to allow work to be done in the background. The `doInBackground` method allows long-running work to not block the UI thread.

However, if you want to display or perform tasks on the UI thread, you need to make sure those happen *on the UI thread*. For example, your line:

```
mDialog.dismiss();
```

should execute in `onPreExecute` because it impacts the UI. Likewise:

```
alertDialog2.show()
```

is trying to change the UI. This should be run in `onPostExecute`.

Fundamentally, though, building an `AlertDialog` is not a long running task at all. None of that needs to be in `AsyncTask` unless you have intentions to expand what happens prior to displaying the next dialog.

See this post here: http://blog.nikitaog.me/2014/10/11/android-looper-handler-handlerthread-i/

Comment: I dont understand what I need to do.

Answer (score 0):

You can't interact with UI non from main-Thread.
The short solution here is:

```
 Handler handler = new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper());
    handler.post(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            // Call UI related methods.
        }
    });
```

Comment: Its working but now I didnt see the ProgressDialog. all this code is in onActivityResult.

Answer (score 0):

I guess AsyncTask implement to your code is something like this:

```
final ProgressDialog mDialog = new ProgressDialog(this);
    mDialog.setMessage("loading");
    mDialog.setCancelable(false);
    mDialog.show();

    final AlertDialog.Builder alertDialog2 = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    new AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>() {
        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            mDialog.dismiss();
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void aVoid) {
            super.onPostExecute(aVoid);
            AlertDialog alertDialog = alertDialog2.create();
            alertDialog2.setTitle("tnxupload");
            alertDialog2.setMessage("tnxupload");
            alertDialog2.setCancelable(false).setPositiveButton("", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                }
            }).setNegativeButton("tnxupload3", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                    // if this button is clicked, just close
                    // the dialog box and do nothing
                    dialog.cancel();

                }
            });
            alertDialog2.show();
        }

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
            return null;
        }


    }.execute();
```